# Merging columns and combining contents

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I am looking to merge two columns and add their contents together, for example

```
X1  X2
3   5
6   9
3   3
0   6
NA  4
NA  NA
```

to create

```
X3
8
15
6
6
4
NA
```

Any indication would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: look for `rowSums()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
X3 <- X1 + X2
```

But this will return NA where you have a single NA. If you want to ignore the NA, and have it return 4 when you add NA and 4, you would do:

```
X3 <- sum(X1, X2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

In dplyr syntax, you could do:

```
df %>% mutate(X3 = X1 + X2)
```

That is, assuming that X1 and X2 are two separate columns within df.

The base R solution will work on separate vectors, even if not in a single df.

Comment: The base R solutions won't run unless you explicitly subset (`df$X1 + df$X2`), use `with`, or litter your global environment with vectors (e.g. by using `attach`). `sum` will attempt to add everything down to one number, too, which is not what is desired. Further, none of these approaches will handle `NA` quite like the OP asked for. tl;dr: You need to run code to make sure it works before posting.

Answer (score 1):

`rowSums` is there for such cases. If data.frame got more than 2 columns then `df` should be replaced with `df[c("X1","X2")]` in below solution.

If OP wants last row to have `NA` then solution can be as:

```
df$X3 <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df), NA, rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE))

df
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1  3  5  8
# 2  6  9 15
# 3  3  3  6
# 4  0  6  6
# 5 NA  4  4
# 6 NA NA NA
```

If last row (with all `NA`) expected sum is `0`, then simple `rowSums` will work as:

```
df$X3 <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)

df
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1  3  5  8
# 2  6  9 15
# 3  3  3  6
# 4  0  6  6
# 5 NA  4  4
# 6 NA NA  0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"X1  X2
3   5
6   9
3   3
0   6
NA  4
NA  NA",
header = TRUE)
```